# One way Anova question

Tags: anova

In one way anova, does the one refer to the independent variable or dependent variable? For example I have three groups: Group A (Music Therapy) Group B (Cognitive therapy) and Group C (no therapy) dependent variable is stress scores

Does the one way refer to the stress scores (dependent variable) or to the therapies of which there are 3?

Please explain

Many thanks
Shindy

Comment: What's wrong with the Wikipedia description of [One-way analysis of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_analysis_of_variance) (see the third paragraph)? The 'many'-way refer to the number of categorical (independent) variables; otherwise, we talk of multivariate analysis of variance (MANOVA) when there are multiple response (dependent) variables.

Answer (score 2):

"One way" means the groups are categorized in one way. For your example: one of three therapies. Three therapies, but only one grouping variable "therapy". SO one-way.

The best way to understand is to extend...

If you also tracked (and wanted to analyze) gender, then you'd have two-way ANOVA, as the groups are categorized in two ways: Therapy and gender. Every individual would be categorized in two ways, which therapy they got, and which gender.

If you also tracked old and young separately, then you'd use three-way ANOVA because there would be three grouping variables: therapy, gender and age group. Every individual would be categorized in three ways, which therapy, which gender and which age group.

Comment: To have your question answered by @HarveyMotulsky is a treat.